# C++ Vector of pointer to objects through user input

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I'm learning C++ using the Visual Studio 2015 ++

I'mstudying it and i can't go through some stuff. maybe you could give me a better insight.

I have learned somethings about classes,structures,arrays and functions.

I want to create a program, that use several players,but it can vary from 2-4 (e.g:

```
class Player{
public: 
    Player(){
        hp=5;
        mana=10;
        alive=false;
    };

    int hp;
    int mana;
    bool alive;
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    // data here //
    retry:
    cin >> numberofPlayers;

    if (numberofPlayers < 2 || numberofPlayers>4)
    {
        cout << "That's Impossible! Don't mock me!" << endl;
        goto retry;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Great!" << endl;
    }
```

So after it , i want to create a vector pointer-to-object which will store the different players variables.

e.g:

Here my problems start :)

```
Player* pointerplayer = new Player();


vector<Player*> vectorPlayer;
Player* pointerplayer = new Player();

for (int i = 0; i < numberofPlayers; i++)
{
    vectorPlayer.push_back(new Player());
    cout << vectorPlayer[i] << endl;
}
```

My problem is when i try to see the Output , i guess the address of the pointer.

```
01639B40
01643F98
01643C80
```

and i want the output to be something like :

```
1 
2
3
```

I'm aware that i am not doing it proprely, but something is escaping me and i am not able to see it proprely.

Because i want to create between 2-4 players, which is based by the user input. and for each player, create a Player() with all the variables for each one. and with the output from (1,2,3,4) depending on the number.

Comment: If you want to see a number, print `i`. But why are you using a vector of pointers instead of just a vector of players?

Comment: As an aside, 1) `_tmain` and `_TCHAR` are Microsoft extensions, and generally aren't portable.  If you use a different compiler in the future (such as GCC or Clang), they probably won't work.  2) [You can make loops without `goto`.](http://ideone.com/e5nAf9)  This is usually preferred, because they're easier to keep track of (the condition tells it whether to loop again or stop, `continue` is basically `goto condition;`, and `break` is basically `goto next_line_after_loop;`).

Comment: Yeah, i had searched about it and maybe is better right? But i thought i could manage to be more efficient in terms of memory management using pointers and properly allocate them in the Heap. @melpomene

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your cout statement to:

```
cout << (i + 1) << endl;
```

Comment: It worked. But now i still can have acess inside the objects members? like hp and such? throught the (*iterator)-> ?

Comment: With vectorPlayer[i].hp